# Select Case not changing all backgrounds and getting conditionals wrong

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening,
After trying some methods to change the properties of Backcolor of multiple labels at the click of a button, I got this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()

        Select Case Label61.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label61.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label61.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label62.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label62.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label62.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label63.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label63.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label63.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label64.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label64.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label64.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label65.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label65.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label65.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label66.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label66.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label66.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label67.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label67.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label67.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label68.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label68.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label68.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label69.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label69.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label69.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label70.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label70.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label70.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label71.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label71.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label71.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label72.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label72.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label72.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label73.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label73.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label73.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label74.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label74.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label74.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label75.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label75.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label75.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label76.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label76.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label76.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label77.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label77.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label77.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label78.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label78.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label78.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label79.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label79.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label79.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label80.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label80.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label80.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label81.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label81.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label81.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label82.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label82.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label82.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label83.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label83.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label83.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        Select Case Label84.Caption
            Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label84.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label84.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select
        End Select

    End Sub
```

It is not everything yet, I need about 60 entries of Select Case. I don't mind copying and pasting one by one, but I am running into 2 problems:
1. Not all the entries are changing the Backcolor so far, onli like 6 or 7. Not sure why.
2. The conditional is getting wrong some times, changing to a color that was not suppose to, meaning it is getting the conditional wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mauro, a few things stand out.  The first is that your select cases are 'nested' -- was that your intention?  Secondly, whenever you type so much perfectly repeated code -- you should be thinking about using a loop or a function call.

Comment: @Ryan B. a loop probably will work, just not sure how to do it

Comment: Are these all text comparisons, or are you comparing numbers?

Comment: Numbers. Changed the property to .value already, but got the same errors @TimWilliams

Comment: maybe also apply `CDbl()` or `CLng()` for example to make sure you're comparing numbers with numbers

Answer (score 2):

You are repeating the same operation over and over, with only one variation, so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()
   Dim n As long

   for n = 61 to 84 'for example
       CheckValue Me.Controls("Label" & n)
   Next n
End sub 


Sub CheckValue(lbl)
   'might need some error handling for non-numeric values...
   lbl.BackColor = IIf(CDbl(lbl.Caption) <= CDbl(TextBox39.Text), _
                       &HC0C0FF, &HC0FFC0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, your code has already made a effect of analysing all the labels declared so far. Now I will go through the number analysis, which is now not changing colors.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you can't install Rubber duck, this is what your code looks like when properly indented.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()

    Select Case Label61.Caption
        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
            Label61.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
            Label61.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

            Select Case Label62.Caption
                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                    Label62.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                    Label62.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                    Select Case Label63.Caption
                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                            Label63.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                            Label63.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                            Select Case Label64.Caption
                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                    Label64.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                    Label64.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                    Select Case Label65.Caption
                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                            Label65.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                            Label65.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                            Select Case Label66.Caption
                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                    Label66.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                    Label66.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                    Select Case Label67.Caption
                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                            Label67.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                            Label67.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                            Select Case Label68.Caption
                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                    Label68.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                    Label68.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                    Select Case Label69.Caption
                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                            Label69.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                            Label69.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                            Select Case Label70.Caption
                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                    Label70.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                    Label70.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                    Select Case Label71.Caption
                                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                            Label71.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                            Label71.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                            Select Case Label72.Caption
                                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                    Label72.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                    Label72.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                    Select Case Label73.Caption
                                                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                            Label73.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                            Label73.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                            Select Case Label74.Caption
                                                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                    Label74.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                    Label74.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                    Select Case Label75.Caption
                                                                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                            Label75.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                            Label75.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                            Select Case Label76.Caption
                                                                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                    Label76.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                    Label76.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                    Select Case Label77.Caption
                                                                                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                            Label77.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                            Label77.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                            Select Case Label78.Caption
                                                                                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                    Label78.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                    Label78.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                                    Select Case Label79.Caption
                                                                                                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                            Label79.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                            Label79.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                                            Select Case Label80.Caption
                                                                                                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                    Label80.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                    Label80.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                                                    Select Case Label81.Caption
                                                                                                                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                            Label81.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                            Label81.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                                                            Select Case Label82.Caption
                                                                                                                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                                    Label82.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                                    Label82.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                                                                    Select Case Label83.Caption
                                                                                                                                                                                        Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                                            Label83.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                                                                        Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                                            Label83.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                                                                            Select Case Label84.Caption
                                                                                                                                                                                                Case Is <= TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                                                    Label84.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                                                                                                                                                                                Case Is > TextBox39.Text
                                                                                                                                                                                                    Label84.BackColor = &HC0FFC0

                                                                                                                                                                                            End Select
                                                                                                                                                                                    End Select
                                                                                                                                                                            End Select
                                                                                                                                                                    End Select
                                                                                                                                                            End Select
                                                                                                                                                    End Select
                                                                                                                                            End Select
                                                                                                                                    End Select
                                                                                                                            End Select
                                                                                                                    End Select
                                                                                                            End Select
                                                                                                    End Select
                                                                                            End Select
                                                                                    End Select
                                                                            End Select
                                                                    End Select
                                                            End Select
                                                    End Select
                                            End Select
                                    End Select
                            End Select
                    End Select
            End Select
    End Select
```

So you should be able to see that Label62  will only be reached is the second case of the first select case is selected, and so on.  I suspect you need to read up on how to iterate a group of controls as this will your life a lot easier.

Comment: never heard of the Rubberduck, but gonna give it a try, because the Option Explicit didn't work =/